# package.json for globally installed packages

Tags: node.js, npm, nuclide-editor

I'm trying to update my nuclide-server. The output of `sudo npm update -g nuclide --verbose` is:

```
$ sudo npm update -g --dev nuclide --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'update',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   '--dev',
npm verb cli   'nuclide',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.9.0
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/nuclide
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:02:17 AM
npm verb request id bf1180b825d1a807
npm verb etag W/"590a3387-6633d"
npm verb lastModified Wed, 03 May 2017 19:46:15 GMT
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nuclide
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nuclide
npm verb headers { date: 'Fri, 12 May 2017 11:02:17 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"590a3387-6633d"',
npm verb headers   age: '132',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-syd1625-SYD',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1494586937.425880,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/nuclide from cache
npm verb get saving nuclide to /home/daniel/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/nuclide/.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir /home/daniel/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb outdated not updating nuclide because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

Searching Google hasn't turned anything up to help this, they all refer to a `package.json` and changing some stuff in there, but I don't have a `package.json` (probably because I'm installing this globally). How do I find the config or do something else to just allow me to update my nuclide package?

**System info:**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- npm version: 4.2.0
- node version: v7.9.0
- Current nuclide version: 217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package.json config your looking for is wherever you installed node orginally, on windows it's at `/usr/local`. On unix systems it can be found via `usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

you can alternatively run `sudo npm root -g` to find where your installtion.

Furthermore it can be found by following the links to the nodejs application which will take you to your installation folder. These links are made after a successful instillation.

Afterwhich you can remove the remove/update the dependancy within `package.json`and run npm i -g again.

Specifically on your version your installation folder is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not in any of these locations, any other ideas?

Comment: According to what you posted `/usr/bin/npm` is where your npm installation is.. so it does exist there?

Comment: Well within that folder you should be able to navigate back to the node folder and into the `node_modules` folder and your package.json is located there.

Comment: Ah it's in `/usr/lib/node_modules`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries @DanielPorteous :-)